# How to volume render simple 3D Data via yt-project

Tags: volume-rendering, yt-project

yt-project is a nice toolkit for volumetric data.
But the dataset it used is a bit of complex, such as Enzo data.
So if I only want to volume render a simple 3d data via yt-project, how to load data?

The simple 3D data only contain the Coordinate(x, y, z) and the density of the point. just as follow:

```
[[x, y, z, density]
[x, y, z, density]
...]
```

Any help appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the x, y, and z coordinates are regularly spaced, you can load your data into yt using the load_uniform_grid function:

http://yt-project.org/doc/reference/api/generated/yt.frontends.stream.data_structures.load_uniform_grid.html

Here is an example that makes a volume rendering using a dataset loaded with load_uniform_grid:

http://yt-project.org/doc/examining/generic_array_data.html#Volume-Rendering-Loaded-Data

If the data are not uniform resolution, then you're going to need to give more information about how the data are laid out before I can help more.

Comment: Thx. Load simple Array data is what i needed at this time.

Comment: But, I use VTK for volume rendering instead now. It seem that it is better if has some knowledge of astronomy before using yt.